# State array does not render properly in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a hacker news clone I am trying to get the ids of the top stories from their api using axios in componentDidMount and then making another axios call to get the stories and push them in a state array but when I try to map over and render that array nothing shows up

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json')
      .then( result => {
        result.data.slice(0, 10).forEach(element => {
          axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + element + '.json')
            .then( value => {
              this.state.posts.push(value)
            })
            .catch(err =>{
              console.log(err)
            })
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
      })
  }


  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <Header title="Hacker News" />
      {this.state.posts.map( (element, index) => <Post key={element.data.id} serialNum={index} postTitle={element.data.title} postVotes={element.data.score} postAuthor={element.data.by} />) }
    </div> 
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Dont do this: `this.state.posts.push(value)` Instead, create an array and do `this.setState({ posts: newArray })`

Comment: Yeah I tried that too still doesn't show up, the weird thing is that when I try to console.log(this.state.posts) the array correctly shows up in the console but nothing shows up in the render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the state like this:

```
 axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + element + '.json')
            .then( value => {
              this.setState({
                posts: [value, ...this.state.posts]
              })
            })
            .catch(err =>{
              console.log(err)
            })
        })
```

This way you're using `setState` and appending every new value to the existing state.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` is called after `Render()` only once. React doesn't know about the state changes unless you use `setState()`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json')
      .then( result => {
        result.data.slice(0, 10).forEach(element => {
          axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + element + '.json')
            .then( value => {
              this.setState({posts: [value, ...this.state.posts]})
            })
           })
         })
        }
```

Use `this.setState({posts : [value, ...this.state.posts]})` instead of `this.state.posts.push(value)`. using ... (spread operator) appends the value to the original posts array.

Comment: If you're using async/await there's no need to chain .then and .catch. And this wont to the trick. this.state.posts will only contain the last post from hacker-news since you're replacing the state in the forEach loop

Comment: Thanks for correction. I use seperate methods for http calls hence it's become a habit. The problem was that he was using push which react doesn't know as a state change. It's better to extract the http call in a seperate method and await the response.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, don't use push for set state. In your code when you make the second request you must change the `setState` method to spread out the new value.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json')
      .then( result => {
        result.data.slice(0, 10).forEach(element => {
          axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + element + '.json')
            .then( value => {
               this.setState(prevState => ({posts: [ value.data, ...prevState.posts]}))
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log("err");
                console.log(err);
            })
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
      })
  }


  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          {this.state.posts && this.state.posts.map( (element, index) => 
             <div key={element.id}>
                {element.title}
             </div>
          )}
        </div> 
    );
  }
 }
```